# OFFSET in Transbase

Tags: transbase

I am working with Transbase DB and stuck on selection of specific range of rows. In MySQL I can do it as folows:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2,3;
```

I know about FIRST() in Transbase, but how about OFFSET?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

just delete offset and it'll work.